# list index out of range ,how to stop at nonexisting value

Tags: python

if i+1 is non existing value then stopn the loop and value of i+1 where i is end of list should not execute.

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in range(len(my_list)):
if my_list[i] == my_list[i+1]:
    print('ok')
```

#IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: don't use `range(len(some_list))` to iterate over some_list

Comment: how about `range(len(my_list) - 1)` instead of `range(len(my_list))`?

Comment: if you want to use len(list) then use len(list)-1 as its length

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i in range(len(my_list) - 1):
if my_list[i] == my_list[i+1]:
    print('ok')
```

Answer (score 1):

Error occurs because `my_list[i+1]` tries to access 6th element of list containing 5 elements.

Not sure what is your goal here, but this is possible fix - since you are comparing current and next element all the time, you can loop from first to 5th element:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in range(len(my_list) - 1):
if my_list[i] == my_list[i+1]:
    print('ok')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in range(len(my_list)-1):
    if my_list[i] == my_list[i+1]:
        print('ok')
```

**If the length of the list is n we have elements from 0 to n-1 only since list indices start from 0.**

[image: Indexing elements]

Answer (score 0):

#hope this code helps you

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    if i in my_list:
        print("ok")
        i = i +1
```

Comment: no,i doesn;t helps